# Sending a JSON HTTP POST request from Android

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, httpurlconnection

I'm using the code below to send an http POST request which sends an object to a WCF service. This works ok, but what happens if my WCF service needs also other parameters? How can I send them from my Android client?

This is the code I've written so far:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  

String http = "http://android.schoolportal.gr/Service.svc/SaveValues";  


HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;  
try {  
    URL url = new URL(http);  
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);   
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);  
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   

    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
    urlConnection.connect();  

    //Create JSONObject here
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
    jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
    jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(jsonParam.toString());
    out.close();  

    int HttpResult =urlConnection.getResponseCode();  
    if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
            urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            sb.append(line + "\n");  
        }  
        br.close();  

        System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

    }else{  
            System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());  
    }  
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {  

         e.printStackTrace();  
}  
catch (IOException e) {  

    e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{  
    if(urlConnection!=null)  
    urlConnection.disconnect();  
}
```

Comment: follow this link. You are trying to send other params, the link blow will give you demonstration how you you can send them after encoding http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Posting parameters Using POST:-

```
URL url;
URLConnection urlConn;
DataOutputStream printout;
DataInputStream  input;
url = new URL (getCodeBase().toString() + "env.tcgi");
urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setDoInput (true);
urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
urlConn.connect();  
//Create JSONObject here
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
jsonParam.put("enable", "true");
```

The part which you missed is in the the following... i.e., as follows..

```
// Send POST output.
printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
printout.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));
printout.flush ();
printout.close ();
```

The rest of the thing you can do it.

Comment: sorry i accepted your answer but now that i'm trying to implement it,i have encountered problems.Where do you pass your parameters?

Comment: jsonParam Object is to send parameters.

Comment: ok but i also want to send an object..how can i achieve this? meaning i have to send now 2 json objects

Comment: In the same way you can add another object also.

Comment: The method write(int) in the type DataOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Instead of write(int); I used                                                                String str = jsonString.toString();
byte[] data=str.getBytes("UTF-8");
printout.write(data);
printout.flush ();
printout.close (); It is working.

Comment: It's an old answer, but it worked great for me to move away from the deprecated DefaultHttpClient. I also moved from the deprecated NameValuePair to a JSON Object. BTW,I had to change the "write" to   "writeBytes".

Comment: printout.write(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8")); we are directly pass jsonObject to server.

Comment: I was getting the error explained above, wrong parameter types for printout.write(), so I used printout.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode(params.toString(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: If you used the above is it working fine or Are you facing any problem..?

Comment: Which are the libraries? pls

Answer (score 14):

try some thing  like blow:

```
SString otherParametersUrServiceNeed =  "Company=acompany&Lng=test&MainPeriod=test&UserID=123&CourseDate=8:10:10";
String request = "http://android.schoolportal.gr/Service.svc/SaveValues";

URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(otherParametersUrServiceNeed.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches (false);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(otherParametersUrServiceNeed);

   JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("ID", "25");
jsonParam.put("description", "Real");
jsonParam.put("enable", "true");

wr.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

References :

1. http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139
2. [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Comment: well i did that but i still get a bad request as a server response.Now let me ask if i did everything corect :When i set the otherparameter should i put param1 or the name of my parameters?also,my json object is the first parameter so first i write this one and after that i write the otherparameters is that right?

Comment: On server side the param sequence does not matter.It seems you are puting json in payload ...
in this `otherParametersUrServiceNeed = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";` put the name of parameters that you server need this is just example ..You should first identify the parameters that you server need in request the add these params and there values in `String otherParametersUrService` as my example demonstrates.

Comment: If it is not confidential you can tell me what addition params your server need ..so that i can put them in above example .

Comment: Well it's not,it is okay if i give you the method signature??:long InsertStudentAbsences(SRV_Students_Absence objStudentAbsences, string Company, string Lng, string MainPeriod, string UserID, string CourseDate);

Comment: do you need something else??

Comment: assuming params exactlty maps on function params.These are params u need `  String otherParametersUrServiceNeed =  Company=acompany&Lng=test&MainPeriod=test&UserID=123&CourseDate=xyz`

Comment: I dont know what is this object `SRV_Students_Absence objStudentAbsences`

Comment: this is just a custom object and i used a JsonObject to create one and pass it so how do i pass this object with the other parameters?

Comment: are u sure ..your web service is serializing and deserializing the json object..i mean it can is converting json from payload to object

Comment: if you are sure there try out  ` String otherParametersUrServiceNeed = Company=acompany&Lng=test&MainPeriod=test&UserID=123&CourseDate=xyz` your other params

Comment: still i don't get how i can pass as a parameter both my custom object and  the other parameters

Comment: you will pass other params same as json object...just like http request arrange parameter and values in String `String otherParametersUrServiceNeed =  "Company=acompany&Lng=test&MainPeriod=test&UserID=123&CourseDate=8:10:10";` and write that string on request.just like example shows..Server should able to map these parameter name Company on String Company ....s on.You have to define mapping on server side

Comment: what is you web service interface and mapping approach...look into them and identify the parameter services want ..because parameter name are case sensitive.You have to find exact name..see request to java variable mapping approch

Comment: @AmirQayyumKhan, what is **urlParameters** in your answer

Comment: where do you get Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length)) ???.

Comment: @PankajNimgade urlparams=> otherParametersUrServiceNeed