# JSON data sent from Android does not show on the server

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to send a JSON data from an android app to a php server. I simply asked the server to print the raw data but it is not shown on the web. I cannot figure out what might be the cause.
DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    new SaveTheFeed().execute();
}

class SaveTheFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        double longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_LONGITUDE, 0.0);
        double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_LATITUDE, 0.0);
        // Create the JSONObject
        JSONObject request = CreateRequest(message, longitude, latitude);
        //JSONObject response = null;
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection client = null;
        try {
            // Establish http connection
            url = new URL("http://********.com/");
            client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            client.setDoOutput(true);
            client.setDoInput(true);
            client.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            client.setRequestMethod("POST");
            client.connect();
            Log.d("doInBackground(Request)", request.toString());
            // Send the JSON object to the server
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            String output = request.toString();
            writer.write(output);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private JSONObject CreateRequest(String message, double longitude, double latitude) {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            request.put("message", message);
            request.put("longitude", longitude);
            request.put("latitude", latitude);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request;
    }
}
}
```

The php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>This is your current location :)
<?php
      $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $request = json_decode($json, true);
      echo ($json);
?>
</h2>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or how do I even know whether the emulator actually sends the data to the url? Now I am not sure which side is having the problem.

Comment: check the respose code from client side by client.getResponseCode() and you can trace the issue

Comment: Why  are you sending a String of the json object to the server? Refer this http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89

Comment: @San  I checked the response code and it is 200. I think this means the connection succeed? But it still doesn't post message to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you missed in your code is to encode your string using `URLEncoder`. Instead of just writing the raw string encode the string before writing it. Try replacing this line:

```
writer.write(output)
```

with this line

```
writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(output,"UTF-8");
```

and let me know the output.
You can also refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911993/sending-a-json-http-post-request-from-android) in stackoverflow

**Update:**

Also don't forget to log the server response in your logcat window. To do that simply add the following lines of code:

```
        String line="";
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            response+=line;
        }
        Log.d("response from server",response);
        reader.close();
```

Comment: Hi! I replaced the line as you suggested. But the app stopped when executing. I don't think it works. :(

Comment: Do I need to modify my php file?

Comment: can you provide the logcat output? It will be easier if you post your logcat output

Comment: also remember if you should add the above code piece before client.close(); i.e right after writer.close() statement