# Sending a parameterized HTTP POST request from Android

Tags: android, json, http-post

**Question:**

I am having trouble accessing cloud data from an Android device. I am using the POST method and expecting a JSON response. I believe I am getting 403 (forbidden) error. But I can access the same data using curl. So I believe I am doing something wrong thus seeking someones assistance.

**Background**

Here is the curl command string that I am trying to replicate. I receive a valid response to this command.

```
curl -X POST --data "token={String}&param1={int}&param2={int}" https://www.example.com/api/dir1/dir2"
```

Below is the android code.

```
        String post_url = "https://www.example.com/api/dir1/dir2";
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                String urlParameters = "token={Key-string}&param1={int}&param2={int}";
                byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes();
                int postDataLength = postData.length;

                URL url = new URL(post_url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",Integer.toString(postDataLength));
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();

                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(stream ));
                String data = null;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((data = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(data);}
                in.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

---

**References:**

- [POST request send json data java HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404252/post-request-send-json-data-java-httpurlconnection)
- [Sending a JSON HTTP POST request from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911993/sending-a-json-http-post-request-from-android)
- [Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily/4206094#4206094)
- [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)
- [How to add parameters to HttpURLConnection using POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post)
- [JSON Parsing, Creating a URLConnection - Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyaay7OTy-w)

Comment: What is the type of urlParameters?

Comment: Be sure what it means before you continue. Look it up.

Comment: I am not too sure. I looked at some of the examples stackoverflow and have being trying different things. But if you look at the curl command I don't specify any types. I think it is a default type.

Comment: You should be sure about the meaning of 403 first was what i said. Look it up.

Comment: And i asked what the type was of the variable urlParameters in your code.

Comment: I did google 403 and it came back as forbidden. But since to curl command works I don't it is an issue with the token key or the parameters. But the type of urlParameters I am just trying things base on what I read on stackoverflow

Comment: The urlparameters are Param1=token key (string), Param2 int and Param3 is int

Comment: If you are asked what the type of your variable urlParameters is you are supposed to say hat it is String or integer or whatever what it is. How did you declare it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104093/discussion-between-mahendra-gunawardena-and-greenapps).

Comment: Just answer these very simple questions here.

Comment: Its hard code. Using Okhttp or volley make our life more easy

Answer (score 1):

You can try make your call in Postman (google chrome plugin), and then click in *Code* link. Postman will generate to you a request in many types of languages, like PHP, java, C, etc.

For example:

Add to your gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
```

Make call in somewhere:

```
    new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           makeCall();
       }
    }.start();
```

Create that class:

```
    public void makeCall() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n   \"param1\":\"data1\"}");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://your_url_here")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        Log.e("okmsg1", response.toString());
        Log.e("okmsg2", response.message());
        Log.e("okmsg3", response.body().string());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("err", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```