# req.user undefined for request from Android app to NodeJS server

Tags: android, node.js, http-post, session-cookies

I am developing an Android app with a NodeJS backend server. I am having problems authenticating the users when requests are made to different pages after the user is logged in.

Once I log in, i store the `set-cookie` value in `SharedPrefs`. Now when I make a POST request, I am sending the `set-cookie` value in the header, i.e. `con.setRequestProperty("set-cookie", cookie);` for authenticating the user on the backend using `req.user.authenticate`.

However, `req.user` is undefined and hence the request fails. What could be wrong over here? Thanks.

Below is my POST request code.

```
    con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "\"Mozilla/5.0\"");

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.accumulate("set-cookie", cookie);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    out.write(jsonParam.toString());
    out.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code:"+responseCode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send data in this format

```
 String data = "";

InputStream inputStream = null;


try{

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.accumulate("set-cookie", cookie);


    data = jsonObject.toString();
    Log.d("json data",data);
    // 1. create HttpClient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // 2. make POST request to the given URL
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(CHECK_WEBSERVICE_URL);
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data);

    // 6. set httpPost Entity
    httpPost.setEntity(se);

    // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    // 9. receive response as inputStream
    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

    // 10. convert inputstream to string
    if(inputStream != null)
        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    else
        result = "Did not work!";


    System.out.print(result);

}catch (Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: isn't DefaultHttpClient() deprecated?

Comment: you use HttpURLConnection what important is to send data in json format. But before sending convert it into string

Comment: trying to make it work using HttpURLConnection. Having trouble with sending the JSON formatted data.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911993/sending-a-json-http-post-request-from-android

Comment: I'm still getting the undefined error for req.user. Updated my question with the new code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127380/discussion-between-user782400-and-siddhesh).