# Android http post results in strange I/O error

Tags: android

I have an activity which has 2 edittext controls and a button. User fills in the edittexts and taps on the button.

Here is the button onclick event:

```
public void submitHelpRequest(View v)
{
    final Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submithelprequest);
    submitButton.setEnabled(false);
    EditText titleElm;
    EditText messageElm;
    titleElm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.helprequestitle);
    messageElm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.helprequestmessage);
    String titleValue = titleElm.getText().toString();
    String messageValue = messageElm.getText().toString();
    new NWThread().execute("snip", titleValue, messageValue);
}
```

Here is my NWThread:

```
private class NWThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... values) {

        Post(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is Post()

```
public void Post(String webAddress, final String title, final String message)
{
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webAddress);

        String auth = new String(Base64.encode(( "snip" + ":" + "snip").getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE| Base64.NO_WRAP));
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

        String json = "";

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("Title", title);
        object.put("Message", message);

        json = object.toString();

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting some strange errors when i click on the button:

```
06-05 16:59:50.971 25135-2533 W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error
[ 06-05 16:59:50.971 25135:25332 W/] Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-05 16:59:50.971 25135-2533 W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
```

Also in Android Studio it says that HttpClient and HttpPost are deprecated, could this be why? And if so which classes in the SDK should I be using?

Edit: Here is the whole activity

```
package ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ScreenSendHelpRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_send_help_request);
    }

    public void submitHelpRequest(View v)
    {
        final Button submitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submithelprequest);
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        EditText titleElm;
        EditText messageElm;
        titleElm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.helprequestitle);
        messageElm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.helprequestmessage);
        String titleValue = titleElm.getText().toString();
        String messageValue = messageElm.getText().toString();

        new NWThread().execute("snip", titleValue, messageValue);
    }

    private class NWThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Post(urls[0], urls[1], urls[2]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Post(String webAddress, final String title, final String message)
    {
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(webAddress);
            HttpURLConnection cnx = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
            cnx.setRequestMethod("POST");
            cnx.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webAddress);

            String auth = new String(Base64.encode(( "snip" + ":" + "snip").getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE| Base64.NO_WRAP));
            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

            String json = "";

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("Title", title);
            object.put("Message", message);

            json = object.toString();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: The problem also seems not to be related to the code you posted, could you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: It will be good if you paste your Activity code, atleast you should paste the code of you onCreate method in Activity, because it's related to your view.

Comment: Volley is not an option as we do not want the overhead of another library. I was originally using Volley

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911993/sending-a-json-http-post-request-from-android

Comment: What "overhead" are you referring to?  Is there a space limitation on targeted devices?

Answer (score 0):

> Also in Android Studio it says that HttpClient and HttpPost are deprecated, could this be why? And if so which classes in the SDK should I be using?

You should use [Volley Library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to do API REST and HTTP call.

I'll write down an example from you using the code from one of my activity [app](https://github.com/Confidential-Storm-Project/ConfidentialStormAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/storm/confidential/parknetwork/LoginActivity.java).
Please note that this example made a JSON request, is it possible also to do a StringRequest that returns a raw string (and also a JSONARRAYrequest).

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "https://www.google.it"; // your URI
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Handle positive response
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//Handle negative response                   
} {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
//put values headers
                    headers.put("user",username.getText().toString());
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);
```

Comment: I originally use Volley but we want to use native objects instead of adding another library

Comment: Native libraries as HttpClient are deprecated since there where a lot or issues. I think that volley (the official library now support​ed by Google ) and OkHttp (Java lib) are the best libraries to use to make http requests.

Comment: Why do you think it's a big overhead?

Comment: I don't but other developers on the project don't want it.

Comment: Well, the native methods for all i know are deprecated. Use the library you prefer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley) is a guide to choose. And also if you want a concrete answer post the code of the Activity