# Parsing JSON Array with BodyParser in Node.js

Tags: java, android, node.js, body-parser

Hi where to convert a json using node.js, to do it using body-parser with the code entered below: I am generated the error below. What is this error due to? how can I solve it? At the bottom I added the front-end java code for sending the json! The strange thing is that the -Note- field is not displayed in the request.body

**Error --> console.log(request.body):**

```
'{"Articoli":':
   { '{"Codice":"VAS-100","Descrizione":"SCHEDA DI ANALISI AD 1 INGRESSO \/ 1 USCITA ALLARME","Prezzo":"35.0"}': '' } }

Error  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**Node.js:**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const myParser = require("body-parser");
    const http = require('http');
    const app = express(); 

    app.use(myParser.json());
    app.use(myParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    //port
    const RunPort=8989;
    //server run on port
    app.listen(RunPort, function () {
        console.log("Server run on Port: ",RunPort);
    })

app.post("/rapportini/generarapportino", async function (request, response) {

    try {
        console.log(request.body);
        var data = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]);
        const ret = await RapportiniController.GeneraRapportino(data.Note);
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.send(JSON.stringify({
            return: ret
        }));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error ", err)
    }
});
```

**JSON:**

```
  {
    "Note": "some note",
    "Articoli":[{
                    "Codice": "CodiceValue 1",
                    "Descrizione": "DescrizioneValue 1",
                    "Presso": "Prezzo 1"
                },
                {
                    "Codice": "CodiceValue 2",
                    "Descrizione": "DescrizioneValue 2",
                    "Presso": "Prezzo 2"
                }]
    }
```

**Front-End Java Code(Android):**

**Generate JSON:**

```
 String ret = "";
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("Note", note);
            JSONArray objarticoli = new JSONArray();
            int size = articoli.size();
            int i = 0;
            System.out.println("\n Size of articoli: " + size);

            for (i = 0; i <
                    size; i++) {

                JSONObject artItem = new JSONObject();
                artItem.put("Codice", articoli.get(i).GetCodice().toString());
                artItem.put("Descrizione", articoli.get(i).GetDescrizione().toString());
                artItem.put("Prezzo", articoli.get(i).GetPrezzo().toString());
                objarticoli.put(artItem);
            }

            obj.put("Articoli", objarticoli);

            try {
                Database db = new Database();
                ret = db.RequestArray("/rapportini/generarapportino", obj, true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("\n Errore login Model");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ErrorManagement.SendError("Errore: Generazione Rapportino: " + ex);
        }
        return ret;
```

**Send of JSON:**

```
String response = "";
        System.out.println("\n Sono in GetResponse con JSONOject: "+object);
        try {
            URL url = new URL("/rapportini/generarapportino");
            byte[] postDataBytes = object.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; ) {
                sb.append((char) c);
            }
            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("\n Errore funzione GetResponse class JSONRequest: "+ex);
        }
        return response;
```

Comment: What is your req.body?

Comment: You are sending wrong json from front-end

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow this: { '{"Articoli":':
   { '{"Codice":"KSI4101000.300","Descrizione":"gemino Bus Scheda GSM\/GPRS (solo PCBA) solo per KS-BUS","Prezzo":"163.35"}': ''
} }

Comment: Why `JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0])`? If you're getting JSON posted to you, I'd expect `JSON.parse(request.body)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried I always have the same error described above

Comment: You are sending wrong data to the API call.

Comment: What are you using for sending request?

Comment: @ArifKhan wait for the front-end code to load

Comment: I'm using java on android, I have add front-end code! @CaptainJackSparrow

Comment: I would suggest you to send hard-coded JSON from android to test if the node.js code is working. According to me, you don't have any problem with Node.js code.

Comment: In Android, use `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Use JSON.stringify then parse it to get desired output

```
var req={ '{"Articoli":': { '{"Codice":"KSI4101000.300","Descrizione":"gemino Bus Scheda GSM\/GPRS (solo PCBA) solo per KS-BUS","Prezzo":"163.35"}': '' } }

var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req));
```

Comment: Ok for but if I do as you wrote: The NOTE field is not displayed anyway!

Comment: it will display.your request.body should have note field ..post request.body here

Comment: this is json with your code : { '{"Articoli":':
   { '{"Codice":"KSI4101000.300","Descrizione":"gemino Bus Scheda GSM\/GPRS (solo PCBA) solo per KS-BUS","Prezzo":"163.35"},{"Codice":"KSI6301000.310","Descrizione":"SIRENA PER BUS KS IMAGO AUTOALIMENTATA","Prezzo":"89.37"}': '' } }  but if I check on jsonlint it tells me it's not properly formatted

Answer (score 1):

You need to set correct `Content-Type` in Android application that is `application/json`

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

and then accept in NodeJS application

```
app.post("/rapportini/generarapportino", async function (request, response) {

    try {
        const ret = await RapportiniController.GeneraRapportino(request.body.Note);
        response.json({
            return: ret
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error ", err)
    }
});
```

Comment: request.body.Note is undefined

Comment: @riki Have you updated your Android code as I above mentioned ?

Comment: What is output of line `System.out.println("\n Sono in GetResponse con JSONOject: "+object);` ?

Comment: this is output: {"Articoli":[{"Codice":"AX 211A","Descrizione":"Feature-rich network camera with CCD sensor, delivers super","Prezzo":"705.0"}],"Note":"sa"}

Comment: You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13988768/3461055 to know how to send json data in POST request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172875/discussion-between-arif-khan-and-riki).